# How to set footer for a msword doc generated from html

Tags: php, html

I am using `header("Content-Type: application/msword");` to generate document.

I need to set a footer for each record of the generated doc. I used page break to open each record in new page.

Thanks

Comment: <p style="margin-bottom: 0.14in; mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always"><br></br></p

      <p style="margin-bottom: 0.14in"><br></br></p>

       <div type=FOOTER>
 <p style="margin-top: 0.46in; margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%; mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
          <td>Date:<?echo ''.$value['today'];?></td>
                  <td style="text-align: right;">Director</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
 </p>
      </div>

Comment: this is te footer portion in my html code.It is working fine in msoffice but not taking the styles in msword.What changes have to make

Answer (score 0):

The answer that comes to mind without seeing some of the code or a better explanation as to what is being generated is:
Add the footer just before every pagebreak.